# CONNECT ERROR: Please check for sufficient write file permissions

Tags: magento

In my Magento site:I am trying to install a plugins via magento connect manager, I copy and paste the extension key then click install and then proceed.I get error

```
CONNECT ERROR: Please check for sufficient write file permissions.
Your Magento folder does not have sufficient write permissions, which downloader requires.
```

Even though all my folders are in 0777 permissions.

Folders and permissions:

```
    app/code/community-0777 
    app/etc/modules-0777 
    app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template-0777 
    app/locale-0777
```

any one have better solution for this? .

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Magento provide cleanup tool to resetting file and directory permission. Check this link:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/resetting_file_permissions

Hope will help!

Answer (score 0):

Go inside your Magento folder & change permissions of ALL FILES & FOLDERS RECURSIVELY to “777”.

copy and paste the following command from your putty.

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
chmod 666 downloader/config.ini
```

You may also need to change the permissions on the pear download file to be able to properly install Magento Connect packages:

```
chmod 777 downloader/pearlib/download/package.xml
```